# WARNING in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js

Tags: angular

i am using [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer) by:

```
{PdfViewerModule} from 'ng2-pdf-viewer/ng2-pdf-viewer';
```

Since Angular 6 the ng build showing the following error but the app still working. What is the problem and how can i solve it?

> WARNING in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\MyProject\node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build'

Comment: Since it is a build "warning", you could actually ignore it.

Comment: @Robert - Thanks but i want to understand the reason of that

Answer (score 3):

This is not an actual solution but a temporary work around as editing files inside node_modules is always a bad approach. You can get rid of this warning by adding the below code in the file.

`node_modules/pdfjsdist/package.json`

Add **zilb: false** here

```
browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "http": false,
    "https": false,
    "node-ensure": false,
    "zlib": false
  },
```

This is still an open issue in Github for this npm

https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/322.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

According to `ng2-pdf-viewer`'s author, the module has a dependency ([PDF.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist)) that is not ES (ECMAScript) compatible, but has CommonJS syntax instead. The problem is that CommonJS modules cannot be optimized and minified, since CommonJS is a standard not intended for use in web browsers (more info about CommonJS and ES [here](https://web.dev/commonjs-larger-bundles/)).

So, there is still no easy way to solve this warning, until `PDF.js` is updated to ES syntax.

### Possible solution

In this [ticket](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/624#issuecomment-669999948), the module's author pointed a [PDF.js ES modulized build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bundled-es-modules/pdfjs-dist) that can be used in the meantime, but you must install it and modify the dependency manually in your Angular package config files.

### You can ignore the warning

There is a way to ignore (hide) the warning, but perhaps this is not advisable, because warnings are there to remind you of an issue that might turn into a problem in a near future. To ignore the warning, add the `allowedCommonJsDependencies` property to `angular.json`:

```
"build": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
    "options": {
        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["ng2-pdf-viewer"],
    }
}
```